# Cannot change the value of registry on Windows10 in VMware

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I changed a value in the registry for custom credential provider on Windows10 in VMware.

After restart, The registry value returns to the previous value.
How can I solve this problem?

(+) I want to change the registry below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are pointed at is the GUID of `Credential Provider` used last time to logon the selected user (SID).

This value will always be overwriten at next logon.

To change the provider used for logon to the system you must log in using different provider.